# simple tooltip in javascript

Tags: javascript, tooltip, css-position

I'm trying to create a very simple tool tip in javascript. Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/softwareeveryday/b1jgsfw2/) for the same. I'm just trying to align the tooltip div around the element which was clicked. Note that clicking on the span link does add a child div tooltip, but the issue is for some reason it is position releative to viewport (and not releative to its ancestor element i.e the link. Any ideas about the positioning?

```
<span class="link">You can</span> click any of <span class="link">these links</span>

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 80px;
}

.link {
  // important!
  position: relative;
}

var links = document.getElementsByClassName("link");

for ( var i = 0 ; i < links.length ; i++ ) {
    links[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var toolTip = createToolTipDOM('tooptip')
    var where = e.target
    if ( hasClass(where, 'link') ) {
        where.appendChild(toolTip)
    }
  })
}

function createToolTipDOM(text) {
    var s = '<div class=tooltip>' + text + '</div>'; // HTML string
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = s;
    var tooltip = div.childNodes[0];
  return tooltip
}

function hasClass(element, cls) {
    return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `// inline comments` in CSS.

So rather than setting `position`, you're setting `//important! position`, which isn't a real CSS property.

Remove the comment and it works. The jsFiddle syntax highlighting has misled you.